# VSCode / Pylance / Disable TypeChecking?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, pylance

I would like to disable the underlining of errors like .text in this example
[image]

But it would be ok for me when eg. driver is wrong written like that

[image]

In my defaultSettings.json the parameter for this option is set:

```
"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off",
```

And in my settings.json this parameter is not at all.

So why is Pylance still underlining the .text-command?
I only want that it is underlining error like wrong written driver?

Comment: Hover the mouse over the wavy line error, what is the error message? Also please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thanks for the response - regarding your latest comment i get your point generally.
But in the above problem i am not sure if a code-snippet is better than the screenshot - cause on the image you clearly see what is highlighted and what is the problem i want to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found the solution -
There are 2 settings.json in VSCode - one for "User" and one for "Workspace":

[image]

I only checked the settings.json for "User" and there was no entry
for the parameter "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode"

But when i checked the "Workspace" settings.json i saw this entry

```
python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic"
```

I changed this to "off" and now everything works again as wanted.

This are the different options for this parameter for the pylance-extension:

- off: No type checking analysis is conducted; unresolved imports/variables diagnostics are produced
- basic: Non-type checking-related rules (all rules in off) + basic type checking rules
- strict: All type checking rules at the highest severity of error (includes all rules in off and basic categories)